# Is MVC good for mobile device?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, java-me, frameworks

Is it good for develop MVC Framework by using J2ME (Resource,Speed,Performance,...)?

Answer (score 3):

MVC is especially appropriate for Mobile applications. These typically have a substantially larger number of specifically purposed user interface modules due to real estate constraints. So the more rigorous attention to SOC that is implied by good MVC design makes keeping the design more tightly focused on single-purpose units that are consistent in their abstractions and play well together.

At the same time, this pattern helps partition functionality into modules that can more cleanly defined with solid coherence while being more precise about limited cohesion where it properly belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MVC eases the design process and promotes portability. Check out [PureMVC](http://trac.puremvc.org/PureMVC_Java/) . The J2ME version is in alpha. [Nokia](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Model-View-Controller_Architecture) is using it.